# Meaning of "let him take Money at Interest, and not buy at Time"

Tags: definition, history-economic-thought

Dudley North ([1691](https://books.google.com/books?id=v5BdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22let%20him%20take%20Money%20at%20Interest,%20and%20not%20buy%20at%20Time%22)):

> let him take Money at Interest, and not buy at Time

What does the above statement mean? I think "take Money at Interest" simply means "borrow at some interest rate". But I have no idea what "buy at Time" means.

(I've read this and the surrounding text several times now but still can't figure out what it might mean. Hopefully someone who's familiar with this and other contemporary works can explain it to me!)